# Looking for PendingResult await() equivalent in New Places SDK Client

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

Background: I have a List of strings which contains the different place IDs. Once a user has selected his location, I have a loop that executes and determines if each place in the list (I obtain the location from the place ID) is near his selected location. I was able to implement this with the old Places SDK but could not migrate it to the new SDK because it seems that the new SDK has no await() equivalent.

Here is my old code:

```
   // contains a list of Offices. Has method getId() which contains the Place ID from Google.
    List<Office> results = obtained from the database...

   // go thru each Location and find those near the user's location
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            // Get the place from the placeID
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.
                    getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, results.get(i).getId());

            // wait for the result to come out (NEED EQUIVALENT IN NEW PLACES SDK)
            PlaceBuffer places = placeResult.await();

            // Get the latitude and longitude for the specific Location
            LatLng latLng = places.get(0).getLatLng();

            // Set the location object for the specific business
            Location A = new Location("Business");
            A.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
            A.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);
            // get the distance of the business from the user's selected location
            float distance = A.distanceTo(mSelectedLocation);

            // if the distance is less than 50m away
            if (distance < 50) { ... do something in code}
```

As you can see in the code above, the old PLACES SDK API has a PendingResult class with await() as one of the methods. This await() as per documentation Blocks until the task is completed.. IN SUMMARY, the code will not proceed till a result is obtained from getPlaceById.

I migrated to the new Places SDK as per documentation and I have issues. Here is my new migrated code based on the Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#fetch_a_place_by_id

```
         for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

            // Get the place Id
            String placeId = results.get(position).getId();
            // Specify the fields to return.
            List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,
                    Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ADDRESS);
            // Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
            FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeId, placeFields)
                    .build();

            // Add a listener to handle the response.
            placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {

                    Place place = response.getPlace();

                    // Get the latitude and longitude for the specific location
                    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

                    // Set the location object for the specific business
                    Location A = new Location("Business");
                    A.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
                    A.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);

                    // get the distance of the business from the selected location
                    float distance = A.distanceTo(mSelectedLocation);

            // if the distance is less than 50m away
            if (distance < 50) { ... do something in code}
```

It seems that key issue here is that in the old code await() blocks the code till its successful hence the for loop does not process. However this is not the case with OnSuccessListener. As a result, with the new migrated code, the for loop proceeds and completes the loop even when fetchPlace is not yet complete getting its results for each iteration. Thus, the code is broken and is unable to get the results needed.

Is there a way to block the code to move till fetchPlace is completed?!

Answer (score 3):

Any Google API task can be waited on by [Google's Task API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) as far as I'm aware.

For example, `findAutocompletePredictions` returns a `Task<>` object. Instead of adding an `onCompleteListener`, you can pass that task to `Tasks.await`.

Instead of this non-blocking way:

```java
OnCompleteListener<T> onCompleteListener= 
    new OnCompleteListener<T> {...}

placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(f)
    .addOnCompleteListener(onCompleteListener);
```

You could pass it on to `Tasks.await()` and make the API call blocking:

```java
T results = null;
try {

    // No timeout
    results = Tasks.await(placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(f));

    // Optionally, with a 30 second timeout:
    results = Tasks.await(
        placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(f), 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // Catch me
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // Catch me, only needed when a timeout is set
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Catch me
}

if (results != null) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do another thing
}
```

Basically, instead of getting a `PendingResult` by default, you're now given a `Task<T>` that you can use however.

Comment: Thanks @Gene for the hint!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using the Task Class. See below:

```
 for (int position = 0; position < results.size(); position++) {
            // Get the placeID 
            String placeId = results.get(position).getAddress();

            // Specify the fields to return.
            List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,
                    Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ADDRESS);

            // Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
            FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeId, placeFields)
                    .build();

            // create a FetchPlaceResponse task
            Task<FetchPlaceResponse> task = placesClient.fetchPlace(request);

            try {
                FetchPlaceResponse response = Tasks.await(task);
                Place place = response.getPlace();

                // Get the latitude and longitude for the specific place
                LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

                // Set the location object for the specific business
                Location A = new Location("Business");
                A.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
                A.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);

                // get the distance of the business from the selected location
                float distance = A.distanceTo(mSelectedLocation);
```

These two codes will ask the system to wait for the response..

Task task = placesClient.fetchPlace(request);

FetchPlaceResponse response = Tasks.await(task);